# Mac Security Update 2015-006 for Mountain Lion fails, fails, fails?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I have been pulling my hair out trying to install Security Update 2015-006 on my MacBook7,1.  Tried AppStore 3x, no go. Downloaded standalone Installer and tried this one 5x. Same result every time. Gets all the way through 95+% to the point where it's simply cleaning up and then it just falls with:

> The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

In the system log:

```
Sep  8 18:30:20 MacBookPro71.local Installer[1022]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
Sep  8 18:30:20 MacBookPro71.local Installer[1022]: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Sep  8 18:30:22 MacBookPro71.local com.apple.kextd[12]: /: kextcache has had enough tries; not launching any more

-----
```

I've already tried deleting the contents of /Library/Updates and /var/folders which has worked in the past but makes no difference this time.

Anybody ?

TIA !

Comment: Perhaps try following the instructions to `set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment variables` and see if it points to the real cuplrit (which prog is causing the CoreAnimation to crash)?  Might be some 3rd party software, which, once disabled, would allow the installer to complete.

Comment: You might have a 3rd party kernel extension that is crashing.  See this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4934668 .  Looks like they deleted a SCSI harddrive driver to stop kextcache from dying.

Comment: I'm having the same issue! I really need a fix. :(